# Invalid date options in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a shell script where I ask the system to return the year, 660days ago.  On my Mac, I use this:

```
date -j -v-660d +"%Y"
```

If run today, that would return 2011.

I'm moving the script to an Ubuntu machine, and I receive an error, stating that the -j and -v options are invalid.

I've looked at the man page, looking for equivalent options, but haven't been able to find a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: OSX uses a BSD-ish system while Ubuntu uses GNU utilities. The respective man pages will be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ date -d '660 days ago' +%Y
2011
```

Comment: Wow, that's a much prettier syntax.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there are more than one version of utilities like `date`. Oftentimes, the version shipped on Linux is not the same as the version shipped on BSD or macOS.

I found the [man page for `date` on FreeBSD](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date), and it says this:

```
 -j      Do not try to set the date.  This allows you to use the -f flag
     in addition to the + option to convert one date format to an-
     other.  Note that any date or time components unspecified by the
     -f format string take their values from the current time.


 -v [+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]
     Adjust (i.e., take the current date and display the result of the
     adjustment; not actually set the date) the second, minute, hour,
     month day, week day, month or year according to val.  If val is
     preceded with a plus or minus sign, the date is adjusted forwards
     or backwards according to the remaining string, otherwise the
     relevant part of the date is set.  The date can be adjusted as
     many times as required using these flags.  Flags are processed in
     the order given.
```

For the GNU version of `date` shipped on Linux, typically, the only way to set the date is to pass `-s`. So we don't need the `-j` flag. The GNU version of `date` has `-d` display the date describe by a passed string.

In your case, you want:

```
$ date -d '660 days ago' +%Y
2021
```